# Assessing login state for each request when authenticated using OpenID, OAuth and/or OAuth 2.0

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, oauth-2.0

I'm in the process of building an expanded login/signup area for my website which includes OpenID, OAuth (Twitter) and OAuth 2.0 (Facebook) sign in options.

Once a user has authenticated successfully and I've stored their access tokens in my database and written a cookie linking the user to their login state, what best practice should I be using to determine that the user's access token is still valid? It seems that having to call the authentication provider for every single request to my site would slow things down for the user and I can't imagine that is what other sites are doing.

My guess is that I should store a cookie which is valid only for the current browser session and thus that cookie will expire when the user closes the browser, forcing a new access token to be generated on the next request (and a new cookie to match). I would also expire the cookie early if the user explicitly logs out.

The only question I have of course is if, for example, the user has my site open in a tab, then they open their authentication provider in another tab and sign out of that site, but continue to browse my site, they won't be logged out of my site, even though technically they're supposed to be able to log out using the third party provider.

Is this one of those "it doesn't really matter" scenarios, or am I approaching the whole thing the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely the service providers do *not* want you pinging their service for every request that comes into your service.  Even Google balks at the thought of *that*.  You could set up some kind of a timeout to check every 5 minutes, but I think your idea of a session cookie is the ideal one.  But yes, it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you are just using these services to log the user in and that's it, then throw away the access token you have as soon as you verify the user is logged in and set your own session or persistent cookie.  You don't need their access token any more.

If you do want to access the user's data on these services, then of course keep the access token around.  But you still probably should maintain your own concept of whether the user is logged in.  If I recall correctly these access tokens are typically long-lived (in OAuth 1.0a anyway) and they won't help you when the user returns to determine whether the user is who they say they are unless either you have your own cookie or you send them through the login service again.

Comment: I actually decided on this method myself (throwing away the access token) in the last couple of days, but it's nice to hear some confirmation that this is a legitimate course of action. Thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using OAuth / OpenId for login purposes, I don't think you should worry about any of it. 
What you should worry about is if *your* users are who they say they are as *their* (OAuth/OpenId provider) users.

If your website intends to interact with Twitter and Facebook, that's a different matter, but still it pretty much solves itself. When you try to interact with FB, while your user has logged out of there, FB will prompt your user to login again.

Bottom line, I think it's really a non-issue.